# Combining Multiple Queries with 'OR' or 'AND' in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two distinct query, and I want to combine them with an 'OR'/'AND' in between. How do I do that?

For example, for the given queries
I just want to run Query1 OR Query2 in the elasticsearch.

Query1:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": { 
            "query_string":{  
               "query":"Batman",
               "default_operator":"AND",
               "fields"::[  
                  "Movies._all"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [  
                  {  
                     "query":{  
                        "filtered":{  
                           "filter":{  
                              "and":[  
                                 {  
                                    "term":{  
                                       "cast.firstName":"Christian "
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {  
                                    "term":{  
                                       "cast.lastName":"Bale"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Query2:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": { 
            "query_string":{  
               "query":"Dark Knight",
               "default_operator":"AND",
               "fields"::[  
                  "Movies._all"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [  
                  {  
                     "query":{  
                        "filtered":{  
                           "filter":{  
                              "and":[  
                                 {  
                                    "term":{  
                                       "director.firstName":"Christopher"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {  
                                    "term":{  
                                       "director.lastName":"Nolan"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to use a [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) 
Something like below will work fine -

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : { 
      "must" : [
        { // Query1 },
        { // Query2}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Use must for AND and should for OR

Comment: This doesn't work as I would expect. It still returns documents even if one of the must clauses doesn't hit.